# Shell script function to execute command with pipe and redirect stdout and stderr to variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a common function to execute any given command and fetch stdout and stderr to a variable. However, command with pipe doesn't work properly.

I also tried with **eval** however, unable to redirect stdout/stderr to a  variable

Here is my function

```
LOGFILE="mylog.txt"

Log() {
    msg=$2
    level=$1
    timestamp=`date "+[%F %T]"`
    echo ""
    echo "" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "$timestamp [$level] ==> $msg"
    echo ""
    echo "$timestamp [$level] ==> $msg" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "" >> $LOGFILE
}

RunCommand() {
    CMD=$1
    MSG1=`printf "Executing command \nCommand: $1"`

    OUTPUT=`$CMD 2>&1`
    ERRCODE=`echo $?`

    MSG2=`printf "\n\nOutput: \n%s" "${OUTPUT}"`
    MSG3=`printf "\n\nError Code: %s\n%s" "${ERRCODE}"`
    Log INFO "${MSG1}${MSG2}${MSG3}"
}

command="df -h | grep /$"
RunCommand "$command"
```

Output:

```
[2019-05-02 05:01:29] [INFO] ==> Executing command
Command: df -h | grep /$

Output:
df: '|': No such file or directory
df: grep: No such file or directory
df: '/$': No such file or directory

Error Code: 1
```

Other commands are working without any error.
Executed script with another long command.

```
[2019-05-02 05:10:20] [INFO] ==> Executing command
Command: find /var/bundle/upgrade/ -type f -size +1b

Output:
/var/bundle/upgrade/upgrade.sh
/var/bundle/upgrade/run_task.py
/var/bundle/upgrade/lib/UpgradeTask.pyc
/var/bundle/upgrade/lib/Constants.pyc
/var/bundle/upgrade/lib/Constants.py
/var/bundle/upgrade/lib/UpgradeTask.py
/var/bundle/upgrade/util/FileSystem.pyc

Error Code: 0
```

Comment: You are trying to put a compound command in a variable.  Have a look at ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Also, have a look at: ["Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead/17529221#17529221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if below changes work for you

```
RunCommand() {
    CMD=$1
    MSG1=`printf "Executing command \nCommand: $1"`

    OUTPUT=$(eval "$CMD 2>&1")
    ERRCODE=`echo $?`

    MSG2=`printf "\n\nOutput: \n%s" "${OUTPUT}"`
    MSG3=`printf "\n\nError Code: %s\n%s" "${ERRCODE}"`
    Log INFO "${MSG1}${MSG2}${MSG3}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small fix :-)

You forgot to add `eval`

```
LOGFILE="mylog.txt"

Log() {
    msg=$2
    level=$1
    timestamp=`date "+[%F %T]"`
    echo ""
    echo "" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "$timestamp [$level] ==> $msg"
    echo ""
    echo "$timestamp [$level] ==> $msg" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "" >> $LOGFILE
}

RunCommand() {
    CMD=$1
    MSG1=`printf "Executing command \nCommand: $1"`

    OUTPUT=`$CMD 2>&1`
    ERRCODE=`echo $?`

    MSG2=`printf "\n\nOutput: \n%s" "${OUTPUT}"`
    MSG3=`printf "\n\nError Code: %s\n%s" "${ERRCODE}"`
    Log INFO "${MSG1}${MSG2}${MSG3}"
}

command="df -h | grep /$"
eval RunCommand "$command"
```

Output on my machine:

`/dev/sda3                      152658276   92448632   52432648  64% /`